# NHibernate / LINQ select MAX in subquery?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I've been trying to get the following SQL

```
SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.VirtualMachines vm
    WHERE vm.SequenceId IN (
        SELECT MAX(SequenceId) FROM dbo.VirtualMachines GROUP BY RequestId
    )
    AND vm.DeletedBy IS NULL
```

...into a LINQ-query for use with NHibernate.

I've been able to get a variation on this working which is based on a corrolated sub-query:

```
var allvms = from vms in this.currentSession.Query<Entities.VirtualMachine>()
             where vms.DeletedBy == null
             where vms.Id == (
                 from activeVms in this.currentSession.Query<Entities.VirtualMachine>()
                 where activeVms.RequestId == vms.RequestId
                 orderby activeVms.Id descending
                 select activeVms.Id).First()
             orderby vms.RequestId
             select vms;
```

...which gives me...

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.VirtualMachines vm
    WHERE vm.SequenceId IN (
        SELECT TOP 1 zvm.SequenceId From dbo.VirtualMachines zvm WHERE zvm.RequestId = vm.RequestId ORDER BY zvm.SequenceId DESC
    )
    AND vm.DeletedBy IS NULL
```

...however I'd rather use the `MAX()` version as (having profiled SQL Server) it's a more efficient query for the dataset I'm working with. Unfortunatly, I can't work out how to wrangle LINQ to give me the query.

I know I can do:

```
from vms in this.currentSession.Query<Entities.VirtualMachine>()
    group vms by vms.RequestId into vmReqs
    select new { 
        LatestSeqId = vmReqs.Max(vms => vms.SequenceId) 
    }
```

which gives me the sub-select (`SELECT MAX(SequenceId) [...]`), but I can't see how to combine this with the query I've already got to do an `IN`. It's possible I'm approaching this in too-SQL a mindset, and I'm trying to approach the query as I would in SQL and there's some other technique I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var subQuer = from vms in this.currentSession.Query<Entities.VirtualMachine>()
              group vms by vms.RequestId into vmReqs
              select vmReqs.Max(vms => vms.SequenceId);

var outerQuery = from vm in this.currentSession.Query<Entities.VirtualMachine>()
                 where subQuery.Contains(vm.SequenceId) && vm.DeletedBy == null;
```

Comment: That appears to have done the job, although the SQL is a bit clumsy (it wraps the sub-select in an `EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM (...) AS t2 WHERE t2.value = t0.SequenceID`) it generates the same execution plan as just the sub-query alone, so that's good enough for me. I also note (with experimentation) that I can merge these into a single query as well.

Comment: @ChrisJ Somewhat surprised with the EXISTS thing... What SQL dialect is this?

Comment: Pretty much same query doesn't work for me. `System.Int32' cannot be used as the data type for a sequence with an ItemExpression of type  'System.Int32'`.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't work with NHibernate 5.2.Throwing for me the same error as above.

Comment: With LINQ, one needs to be careful with statements like "pretty much the same query". The devil and the details and all that. @RomanArtiukhin I think you should post you query as a new question instead.

Comment: Found related bug - https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1124. @OskarBerggren your are actually participant of this discussion. So your should be aware of not working group by subquery in NHibernate.